# why after the first push head is still null?

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to create singly-linked list. After the first push, `head` is still **null**. Why is the head not updated after the first push?

```
using namespace std;

typedef struct node {
    int data;        // will store information
    node *next;     // the reference to the next node
};

void push(node*,int);
void print(node*);

int main()
{
    node* head = NULL;  //empty linked list
    push(head, 2);
    if (head == NULL) {
        cout << "vrvrvr";
    }
    push(head, 3);
    push(head, 5);
    push(head, 2);
    //print(head);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void push(node* x, int y){
    node *temp = new node();
    if (x == NULL) { // check linked list is empty
        temp->next = x;
        temp->data = y;
        x = temp;

    }
    else {
        node *temp1 = new node();
        temp1 = x;
        while (temp1->next != NULL) { // go to the last node
            temp1 = temp1->next;
        }
        temp1->next = temp;
        temp->data = y;
        temp->next = NULL;
        delete temp1; // 'temp' node will be the last node
    }
}

void print(node* x){
    node *temp1 = new node();
    temp1 = x;
    while (temp1->next != NULL) {
        cout << temp1->data << endl;
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're assigning to a `node*` parameter. This has as much effect as assigning to an `int` parameter. There is nothing special about pointers. If you want to modify a variable, you need either a reference or a pointer to the variable you want to modify.

Comment: Read about passing parameters by reference

Comment: `void push(node* x, int y)` should have been `void push(node*& x, int y)`

Comment: i ll try that solution now :)

Comment: Exception thrown: read access violation.

temp1 was 0x1.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued. 

Still not working

Comment: `int increment (int j) { j = j + 1; } void main() { increment(2); printf("%d", 2); } ` <- Why doesn't this print 3? Same answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with `push` is that the changes made to `x` in the function are local to the function. It does not change the value of `head` in `main`.

You can fix that by changing the argument type to `node*&`.

```
void push(node*& x, int y) {
   ...
}
```

The other problems I see are in the block:

```
else {
    node *temp1 = new node();
    temp1 = x;
    // Problem 1:
    // After this, the memory returned by the previous line is lost.
    // It is a memory leak.

    while (temp1->next != NULL) { // go to the last node
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }
    temp1->next = temp;
    temp->data = y;
    temp->next = NULL;
    delete temp1; // 'temp' node will be the last node
    // Problem 2:
    // You are deleting a node from the linked list.
    // The linked list now has a dangling pointer.
}
```

You can correct those problems by using:

```
    node *temp1 = x;
    while (temp1->next != NULL) { // go to the last node
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }
    temp1->next = temp;
    temp->data = y;
    temp->next = NULL;
}
```

**Suggested improvements**

1. Remove `typedef` from definition of `node`. It is a dangling `typedef` in your posted code. Also, you can use `node` without a `typedef` in C++.

   ```
   struct node {
      int data;
      node *next;
   };
   ```
2. Add a constructor to `node`.

   ```
   struct node {
      node(int d) : data(d), next(nullptr) {}
      int data;
      node *next;
   };
   ```

   That will simplify your code in `push`.

   ```
   void push(node*& x, int y){
      node *temp = new node(y);

      if (x == NULL) { // check linked list is empty
         x = temp;
      }
      else {
         node *temp1 = x;
         while (temp1->next != NULL) { // go to the last node
            temp1 = temp1->next;
         }
         temp1->next = temp;
      }
   }
   ```